# Tracking run time values in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, profiling

I have a use case where I need to track few variables at runtime and obtain their range of values (ex: -0.156 to 10.165). Can this be done in Visual Studio where I specify the set of interesting variables and after execution, I obtain the range of values?

Comment: You could  write the variable values to the Visual Studios Output window, or you could add a breakpoint, and view the range of the values during the same breakpoint was hit again, or custom code or other. Is it what you want to get?

Comment: Could you get useful information from my suggestion? If you get any latest information, feel free to let me know.

Comment: I am working with a program where I need to track the runtime values of multiple variables and extract the range of values seen during an execution. Having a breakpoint for each variable and manually tracking the range is practically impossible. The other solution is to use tracepoints and use the Visual Studio's 'Action' feature to output the changed value to the console. This solution is also not practical in my case because the tracepoint is hit a large amount of time and it slows down the execution to an extent where it won't complete even after 10 to 20 mins.

Comment: The only feasible solution (from my understanding) is to add code to manually track the range of values using variables and then output the value at the end of execution. This solution won't scale as it will be cumbersome to change the tracking code whenever the underlying code changes. But currently, this was the fastest solution I could find.

Comment: Based on your requirement, I agree with you, custom code to capture the value would be a good path. Anyway, if I find other good solutions, I will share it here.  Since you get the answer, you could add your solution as an answer(not as a comment), and it would help other community members who get the same issue. Have a nice day:)

Comment: Sure. Do let me know if you find any other answers. Thanks! :)

Comment: I will. You could mark your reply as the answer, so it could help other community members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[After figuring out a feasible solution, I am posting my comments here.]

I am working with a program where I need to track the runtime values of multiple variables and extract the range of values seen during an execution. Having a breakpoint for each variable and manually tracking the range is practically impossible. The other solution is to use tracepoints and use the Visual Studio's 'Action' feature to output the changed value to the console. This solution is also not practical in my case because the tracepoint is hit a large amount of time and it slows down the execution to an extent where it won't complete even after 10 to 20 mins.

The only feasible solution (from my understanding) is to add code to manually track the range of values using variables and then output the value at the end of execution. This solution won't scale as it will be cumbersome to change the tracking code whenever the underlying code changes. But currently, this was the fastest solution I could find.